# Problems with a Dynamic Array of Static Arrays

Tags: c++, arrays

I do not plan on changing the size of my dynamic array. The reason I want to create a dynamic array of static arrays (which contain shorts) is so that I can return that array in a function (not defining the size of that array until I'm in that function).

My first question then, is how do I return such an array? Functions don't let you return a pointer without a type & I'm unable to find out how to define a pointer with type `array`.

This brings me to my second question, which is how do I correctly define a dynamic array of static arrays? I have searched for this online, but none of the answers have been too helpful.

One way to do it is to declare: `short (*array)[size]` but the problem with this is that I don't know how to initialize the array in that case, and `size` has to be a literal.

I could do this:

```
typedef short column[size];
column * row = NULL;
row = malloc(rowMax * sizeof(column));
row[0][0] = 10;
```

but again, `size` has to be a literal; and even if `size` is a literal, I receive an error stating that a value of type "void *" cannot be assigned to an entity of type "column *".

If any of you have a solution that doesn't use vectors that would be greatly appreciated; as the vector class is larger than the array class.

Comment: _"as the vector class is larger than the array class."_ There's no _array class_ in your sample.

Comment: And if you are using C++11 or later, you can use [`std::array`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) for the static array.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I tried using: `short (*array)[size] = new std::array[row];` but that results in the error: `argument list for class template std::array is missing`.

Comment: In C++11, `size` can also be a `constexpr` value.

Comment: What is your version of C++? Please show enough code to generate your errors. Please edit your updates into your question.

Comment: `malloc()` returns a `void*` pointer.  In C++, you have to type-cast that pointer when assigning it to a typed pointer: `collumn *row; row = (collumn*) malloc(rowMax * sizeof(collumn));`  in C, you don't need the typecast.  But in C++, you should be using `new[]` instead of `malloc()`: `row = new collumn[rowMax]; ... delete[] row;`

Comment: @RemyLebeau Thank you so much for that! Many of the answers I was seeing were in C. Since I'm not familiar with most of C, or `malloc`, I had no idea that it translated to C++'s `new` when dealing with arrays.

Comment: You say "static array" but you seem to mean *array*, ie a sequence of objects either defined by `[]` or returned from `malloc` or `new`. Ironically you seem to be allocating them *dynamically*, ie via `malloc` or `new`. You say "dynamic array" but you seem to mean *array of pointers (into arrays)*. Ironically you seem to be allocating them *statically*, ie via `[`*`constexpr`*`]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C++11 one could use `std::array` from `<array>` and do:

```
constexpr std::size_t const cols = 42u; // static size
using MyStaticArray = std::array<short, cols>; // static array type
// Or in C++03 and earlier: typedef short MyStaticArray[42u];

std::size_t const rows = someValue; // dynamic size
MyStaticArray * dynamicArray = new MyStaticArray[rows];
// Or better: std::vector<MyStaticArray> dynamicArray(rows);

for (std::size_t row = 0u; row < rows; ++row)
  for (std::size_t col = 0u; col < cols; ++col)
    dynamicArray[row][col] = rows * cols;
```

PS: Also give upvotes to Remy Lebeau below for his comments helped to improve this post.

Comment: If you are going to go to the trouble of using `std::array`, you may as well use `std::vector` for the dynamic array: `std::vector<MyStaticArray> dynamicArray(rows);`  Even if you are not using C++11, you can still use `std::vector`, just typedef the static array using `typedef short MyStaticArray[cols];`

Answer (score 1):

For the sake of saving time, just create a vector of static arrays

```
std::vector<std::array<Type, n>>
```

Not sure why the size difference matters, it's only a few Kb.

Also, if you're going to write C code in a C++ app... you're gunna have a bad time.